# Excel export with stimulsoft

Tags: c#, excel, stimulsoft

How can I export a stimulsoft report to excel format with only data and header ?

```
await report.ExportDocumentAsync(StiExportFormat.Excel2007, ms);
```

It's a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  await report.ExportDocumentAsync(StiExportFormat.Excel2007, ms,
        new StiExcel2007ExportSettings
        {
            DataExportMode = StiDataExportMode.DataAndHeaders
        });
```